# Code snippets within lists (Creole wiki)

Tags: list, wiki, code-snippets, creole

While [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikis-and-wikipedia) is still in Area 51, I'd like to ask this question about using the Creole wiki markup. I have the following code:

```
# Initial instructions here.
# Some instructions here. See code snippet below.
{{{
#!python

def foo():
  return bar
}}}
# More instructions here. Why does the numbering restart at 1?
# Final instructions.
```

When that code is parsed, I'd get the following:

> 1. Initial instructions here.
> 2. Some instructions here. See code snippet below.
>
> ```
> def foo():
>   return bar
> ```
>
> 1. More continuing instructions here. Why does the numbering restart at 1?
> 2. Final instructions.

**Question:** How do I embed code snippets within a list so that the list items below the code snippet won't restart at 1?

Answer (score 0):

Inline preformatted text works in lists. You can use this to approximate block preformatting by separating each line. This isn't a great solution, but it might work for some cases.

```
# Initial instructions here.
# Some instructions here. See code snippet below.
** {{{#!python}}}
** {{{}}}
** {{{def foo():}}}
** {{{  return bar}}}
# More instructions here. Why does the numbering restart at 1?
# Final instructions.
```

Yeilds:

```html
<ol>
 <li>Initial instructions here.</li>
 <li>Some instructions here. See code snippet below.
 <ul>
  <li><tt>#!python</tt></li>
  <li><tt></tt></li>
  <li><tt>def foo():</tt></li>
  <li><tt>  return bar</tt></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li>More instructions here. Why does the numbering restart at 1?</li>
 <li>Final instructions.</li>
</ol>
```